# Pandas Create New Column Based on Value in Another Column, If False Return Previous Value of New Column

Tags: python, pandas

this is a Python pandas problem I've been struggling with for a while now.  Lets say I have a simple dataframe df where df['a'] = [1,2,3,1,4,6] and df['b'] = [10,20,30,40,50,60].  I would like to create a third column 'c', where if the value of df['a'] == 1, df['c'] = df['b'].  If this is false, df['c'] = the previous value of df['c'].  I have tried using np.where to make this happen, but the result is not what I was expecting.  Any advice?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1,2,3,1,4,6]
df['b'] = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
df['c'] = np.nan
df['c'] = np.where(df['a'] == 1, df['b'], df['c'].shift(1))
```

The result is:

```
   a   b     c
0  1  10  10.0
1  2  20   NaN
2  3  30   NaN
3  1  40  40.0
4  4  50   NaN
5  6  60   NaN
```

Whereas I would have expected:

```
   a   b     c
0  1  10  10.0
1  2  20  10.0
2  3  30  10.0
3  1  40  40.0
4  4  50  40.0
5  6  60  40.0
```

Comment: Since your `df['c']` is all `np.nan`, `df['c'].shift(1)` in `np.where` would always be `np.nan`.

Comment: well, as np.where should be taking the previous value of df['c'], and since the first value is 10, the next one should be 10 as well, so this behavior is odd.

Comment: No, `np.where` behavior is right. no.where works on the current state  of `df['c']`. In which all values are `np.nan`. It does not take every rows with its updated values into consideration as it moves from one row to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.c.ffill(inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   a   b     c
0  1  10  10.0
1  2  20  10.0
2  3  30  10.0
3  1  40  40.0
4  4  50  40.0
5  6  60  40.0
```